# stdout hangs on blinking cursor

Tags: rust, process, stdin, stockfish

I have a process struct, which holds a process handle:

```rust
pub struct Process {
    process: Child,
    init: bool
}
```

I have a seperate function where I can 'talk' to the engine.

```rust
    fn talk_to_engine(&mut self, input: &String) -> String {
        let stdin = &mut self.process.stdin.as_mut().unwrap();
        stdin.write_all(input.as_bytes()).expect("Failed to write to process.");

        let mut s = String::new();
        return match self.process.stdout.as_mut().unwrap().read_to_string(&mut s) {
            Err(why) => panic!("stdout error: {}", why),
            Ok(_) => s
        }
    }
```

Yet when I run the function, I get a blinking cursor in the terminal and it does nothing.

EDIT: I call the init_engine function which in turn calls the above mentioned function:

```rust
    /// Initialize the engine.
    pub fn init_engine(&mut self, _protocol: String, depth: String) {
       //Stockfish::talk_to_engine(self, &protocol);
       let output = Stockfish::talk_to_engine(self, &format!("go depth {}", &depth));

        print!("{:?}", output);
       self.init = true;
    }
```

if you call init_engine, let's say, like this: `struct.init_engine("uci".to_string(), "1".to_string());`

Comment: Try calling `stdin.flush()` after `stdin.write_all(...)` to ensure that the process receives the string you send to it. Also: does the command you send to stockfish not need a newline?

Comment: Also as @Masklinn pointed out, `read_to_string()` is most likely not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Without any information a full reproduction case, or even knowing what the input are and subprocess are it's impossible to know, and hard to guess. Especially as you apparently didn't even try to find what was blocking exactly.

But there are two possible problem points I can see here:

1. The driver will only reads the output once all input has been consumed, if the subprocess interleaves reading and writing it could fill the entirety of the output pipe's buffer *then block on writing to stdout forever*, basically deadlocking.
2. `read_to_string` reads the entirety of the stream, meaning the subprocess must write everything out *and terminate or at least close its stdout*, otherwise more output remains possible, and the driver will keep waiting for it.

Comment: I've edited my question with (basically) my whole program and a sample input.